# Sent bitcoin with no history of transactions

Tags: lost-transactions

I sent 0.029044 bitcoins a few hours ago to this address 16CCgdxQ1qc89Yp2rZwzBx4Pfw83DtCyrP but don't see them yet. My account balance has become zero with no history of transactions. What should I do? Can I return the bitcoins? How to see a transaction if it is not in the history?

Comment: which wallet are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Everything is fine, the bitcoins are back.
With some peculiarity:)